# Windows 7 latency when typing

Tags: windows-7, delay, typing

When I type, there has been a slight delay between when the key is pressed and when the letters appear on screen. Occasionally when typing, nothing appears for a second and then the letters stutter onto screen with some repeating and other keys missed.

I'm running Windows 7 x64 SP1 with an i5-3450 cpu and an ssd as my main drive. My first thought was that it might be caused by the Autohotkey script I have running, but the problem persists without it. The keyboard works fine on other computers.

I've checked resource manager for CPU, memory, disk, and network utilization when this happens, and no resource seems to be maxing out.

Comment: Have you checked your CPU utilization when this happens? That's usually the main cause when this happens. You have a pretty good CPU, but there could be something that's really hogging it for some reason.

Comment: @DrZoo, Good point, but no, cpu utilization is low when this happens